# Incompatible Type Error in Android Project

Tags: java, android

This is an Android project. I'm completely new to Java (just started learning). As stated in the title, I'm getting an **Incompatible Type Error**

I've attached the respective method here :

```
public void init(Map map) {
    this.productIds = new ArrayList();
    try {
        if (map.containsKey("products")) {
            for (Entry<String, Object> "//Error Lies here" entry : ((HashMap) map.get("products")).entrySet()) {
                InAppProduct productId = new InAppProduct();
                productId.productId = ((String) entry.getKey()).toLowerCase();
                HashMap<String, Object> extraValues = (HashMap) entry.getValue();
                if (extraValues.containsKey(ShareConstants.MEDIA_TYPE)) {
                    productId.productType = (String) extraValues.get(ShareConstants.MEDIA_TYPE);
                }
                if (extraValues.containsKey("days")) {
                    productId.days = ((Integer) extraValues.get("days")).intValue();
                }
                this.productIds.add(productId);
            }
            return;
        }
        this.productIds = new ArrayList(ConfigurationFetcher.this.mDefaultsDelegate.getDefaultsInAppPackages());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Error is :

> Required `Object` but found `Entry <String, Object>`

Let me know if you need additional code or any details. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set` is a generic type. It is a container that can contain any kind of object.

In your case, it seems that your Set contains `Map.Entry<String, Object>` objects but since you don't specify that anywhere, Java assumes your Set contains `Object`s (the Java class that all other classes derive from) and produces an *Incompatible Type Error*.

Here's a slightly altered version of your code that should work.

```
public void init(Map map) {
    this.productIds = new ArrayList();
    try {
        if (map.containsKey("products")) {

            // ***** We now specify the type of object that the Set contains.
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet = ((HashMap) hm.get("products")).entrySet();

            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : entrySet) {
                InAppProduct productId = new InAppProduct();
                productId.productId = ((String) entry.getKey()).toLowerCase();
                HashMap<String, Object> extraValues = (HashMap) entry.getValue();
                if (extraValues.containsKey(ShareConstants.MEDIA_TYPE)) {
                    productId.productType = (String) extraValues.get(ShareConstants.MEDIA_TYPE);
                }
                if (extraValues.containsKey("days")) {
                    productId.days = ((Integer) extraValues.get("days")).intValue();
                }
                this.productIds.add(productId);
            }
            return;
        }
        this.productIds = new ArrayList(ConfigurationFetcher.this.mDefaultsDelegate.getDefaultsInAppPackages());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map.get("products")).entrySet()` is a set of products, each product is a `Object`, not `Entry <String, Object>`.

This should work:

```
public void init(Map map) {
    this.productIds = new ArrayList();
    try {
        if (map.containsKey("products")) {
            for (Object entry : ((HashMap) map.get("products")).entrySet()) {
                InAppProduct productId = new InAppProduct();
                productId.productId = ((String) entry.getKey()).toLowerCase();
                HashMap<String, Object> extraValues = (HashMap) entry.getValue();
                if (extraValues.containsKey(ShareConstants.MEDIA_TYPE)) {
                    productId.productType = (String) extraValues.get(ShareConstants.MEDIA_TYPE);
                }
                if (extraValues.containsKey("days")) {
                    productId.days = ((Integer) extraValues.get("days")).intValue();
                }
                this.productIds.add(productId);
            }
            return;
        }
        this.productIds = new ArrayList(ConfigurationFetcher.this.mDefaultsDelegate.getDefaultsInAppPackages());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get error at `productId.productId = ((String) entry.getKey()).toLowerCase();` the error is showing at `entry.getKey()` getKey() is not getting resolved.